# C# - How to Change Dynamically the Mask of the MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, validation, custom-controls, maskedtextbox

Here's the problem:
I'm using a MaskedTextBox for phones masks. But, the Mask must accept two kinds of mask, like, the default mask is like this (00) 0000-0000, but sometimes the mask need to have one more slot, like this (00) 0000-00000.
This process must be dynamic. If the user type more than 10 chars, the MaskedTextBox will change his own mask.
Some time ago, I made it using VB.Net, but now, I need to do this using C#.

Here's just a example using VB.NET that I made some time ago.

```
Private Sub MaskedTextValidacao_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Validating
    Me.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals

    If Me.Text.Contains(" ") Or Me.Text.EndsWith(" ") Or Me.Text.StartsWith(" ") Then
        Me.Text.Replace(" ", "")
    End If

    If Me.Text.Count.Equals(10) Or Me.MaskCompleted.Equals(True) Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Me.Text = Me.Text.TrimEnd
    ElseIf Me.Text = "" Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.White
    Else
        Me.BackColor = Color.LightCyan
    End If

End Sub
```

Now, I'm trying to make something better and using C#.

Can someone help me? I mean, just give me a light, because I'm stuck!

Comment: Strings are immutable.  Your `Replace()` call is useless.  Its `If` is even more useless.

Comment: are you familiar with using and or creating Enum you could create a mask that way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this :

```
 public class CustomMaskedBox : MaskedTextBox
{
    public CustomMaskedBox()
    {
        this.MaskInputRejected += CustomMaskedBox_MaskInputRejected;
        this.Enter += CustomMaskedBox_Enter;
        this.Leave += CustomMaskedBox_Leave;
    }

    void CustomMaskedBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MaskFull)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Mask = "(00) 0000-0000";
            this.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

        if (!this.MaskCompleted)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        }

    }

    void CustomMaskedBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }

    void CustomMaskedBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MaskFull)
        {
            this.Mask = "(00) 0000-00000";
            this.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this I think( where maskedTextBox1 is control on form): So when the form starts it defaults to the Mask of

```
 this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(00) 0000-0000";
```

When the user enters the values and the Mask is full then you can change the mask again:

```
 private void maskedTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.maskedTextBox1.MaskFull)
        {
            this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(00) 0000-00000";
        }
    }
```

You can customise the key press/key down events to pick up the values dynamically.

Comment: What if they add ed the additional character some where it should not belong?

Comment: The mask is specifying the characters that the users can enter so can you please explain the question bit more as couldn't understand it?

Comment: My question is shouldn't you validate that the input fits the mask in this case? what if they have input something well outside of the either mask?

Comment: that is the task of Validating event of the MaskedTextbox which will fire once the  user moves out after entering the data. You could use the same validation if required before changing the mask.

Comment: To enhance it , you could also hook to MaskInputRejected event to notify user( by changing color or tooltip) of any invalid data

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. I tried something and it's working.

It's use colors to identify if the field are Right or not. It also modify the mask.
Most part of it are in the Leave Event.

Think:

1. User type a number with 10 digits (00) 0000-0000
2. User leave the field
3. Then, the User enter again in the field and add a new digit (00)
       0000-00000
4. User leave the field
5. Again, the user enter in the field and remove some digit (00)
   0000-0000

The EVENT LEAVE can handle with this. I just like to know how can I do it in a "Professional Way", 
I mean, this MaskedTextBox will be a part of a Class with others Custom Controls, so...**there's a better way to do something like I did?**

Here's the code that I made, and again, **thanks guys!!**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MaskedTextBox
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (maskedTextBox1.MaskFull)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(00) 0000-00000";
            maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        }
    }


    private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }


    private void maskedTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (maskedTextBox1.MaskFull)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Mask = "(00) 0000-0000";
            maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }

        if (!maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, Why don't you derive the Control from MasketTextBox itself and then the control can have properties which you can customise on the form. All this logic can then sit inside the control itself and it will be totally reusable

Comment: I made something like that using VB.Net, with Inherits. But with C# I don't know yet how to do it. What I made is a Custom Control, where I added a MaskedTextBox, and then, coding some events. After that, I'll import that Project to my Main Solution, where I have my forms and others stuff.